# using c++ standard library algorithms with valarray

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I'm trying to avoid reimplementing my own clumsy versions of standard algorithms, and thus am playing with the standard library versions. Since I'm no expert in C++, I proceed with caution and full debug options switched on.

Specifically, I'm using a binary search on a `valarray` container. The following code block seems to produce correct results, and `valgrind` does not complain. Still, I do feel I'm on a slippery slope as I'm not sure if what I'm doing is really allowed or am I just being let out by the compiler.

A representative piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <algorithm>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main(){

 valarray<double> v(10);
 for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; ++i){
   v[i]=2. *i ; 
   cout<<v[i]<<"  ";
 }
 cout << "\n";

 double what=17;
 double* it=lower_bound(&v[0], &v[10],what) ; 

 cout<<it-&v[0]<<" "<<typeid(&v[0]).name()<<" ";
 cout<<typeid(it).name()<<" "<<typeid(it-&v[0]).name()<<"\n"; // ???

 int idx=it-&v[0];
 cout<<"v["<<idx<<"]="<<v[idx]<<"\n";
}
```

Questions:

1. Is what I'm doing here really legal?
2. How come the difference between two pointers to double becomes an int? (in the line with the `???` comment)
3. <s>What is the overhead for the type conversion? --- I *am* concerned with efficiency as this sort of functionality is going to sit in the part of the code which takes more than 90% of the computation time.</s>

Comment: I fixed my answer to not be completely wrong, and I think it's complete as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're using an `int` to index into the `valarray`. That's valid for the example, but not in general. Use an `std::size_t` to index into a `valarray`. (The same goes for `std::vector` and ordinary arrays.)
2. The difference between two pointers to any type is of an unspecified integer type, likely `int` or `long` and always small enough to fit in an `std::ptrdiff_t`.
3. Which conversion?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Is this a feature of a particular version of gcc I'm using, or is this portable?

Comment: @Zhenya: as I said (in the edited post), unspecified. If you want to store the difference between two pointers, always use a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: I personally would prefer to use indices [it's an array with of a fixed size, after all], but the `lower_bound` wants to return something iterator-ish. But as long as it's an integer type, it's safe to use as an index, I presume. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is all defined behavior that will continue to work on any implementation. Looking at the various documentation for valarray, it looks like it has to be legal in order for all the other things about `::std::valarray` to hold true. The bare pointers to the elements should remain perfectly valid until the `resize` member function is called or the `valarray` is destroyed.

The only real question is whether or not `valarray` is required to hold its elements contiguously or not. And I found the [answer to that question in a post](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++.moderated/Address-of-first-member-of-valarray). I'll excerpt it here:

> Yes, valarray also uses contiguous
>   storage. The specific wording from the
>   standard is ($26.3.2.3/3): The
>   expression &a[i+j] == &a[i] + j
>   evaluates as true for all size_t i and
>   size_t j such that i+j is less than
>   the length of the non-constant array
>   a.

Of course, slices still won't be able to be used directly with the standard algorithms, though creating a slice iterator shouldn't be too hard. It'd be pretty easy to make a bidirectional one, but much harder (lots of tricky math you have to get exactly right) to create a random access iterator.

The difference between two pointers becomes (as someone else said) `::std::ptrdiff_t`. This will be a different type on different platforms. I use gcc under 64-bit Fedora 14, and the type is `long` for me. There is no overhead in this 'type conversion'. It isn't even a conversion really. The compiler just does the subtraction as if the two pointers were plain old numbers and the result is a plain old number of some type. The use of `::std::ptrdiff_t` for the type is to ensure that the type of number used is big enough to hold the difference between any two pointers in the system.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that `valarray` is contiguous in memory [that's why I used in first place]; I do need random access, for which indices are just fine. It was this pointer-to-integer correspondence which got me puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

These `it-&v[0]` really scare me .. did you mean `it->v[0]`? The return value of lower_bound is of type `valarray<double>::iterator`, please use that instead of `double*`! All the other derefencing issues will go away automatically. For example you can do `*it` and `it++` but you can't do `it->v[0]`, because it's not a pointer but an iterator. It may very well be an `v.end()`-iterator making all your attemts to get its value illegal.

More info on iterators: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/iterator/start

Edit: Oh now I see, you are using scary pointer arithmetic! That's sooo C, we don't do that anymore ;)

Comment: valarray does not support iterators.

Comment: @Zhenya valarray support iterators in C++11